# Put arraylist of hashmap into another

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap

I want to put an `ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>` into another `ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>`. How can I do that?

I was trying with the assignment operator (`=`) but I found out that it just points to the reference, I want to put the elements into another.

Comment: So you want to copy everything, including he objects within the `HashMap`, correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
List<HashMap<String, Object>> newList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,Object>>();
for (HashMap<String, Object> hm: oldList) {
    newList.add(hm);
}
```

Comment: I didn't make any point about addAll. My method is pretty quick and dirty, but for a real eye-opener, look at the source of addAll() in ArrayList.java.

Comment: He he, sorry, you did not make a point indeed. I guess I was making it, that addAll would be more compact and do the same

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [`addAll`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#addAll%28java.util.Collection%29) method, but bear in mind that'll not duplicate the HashMaps and much less the Objects within!

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new `ArrayList` Object and just call the `addAll` method and pass the ArrayList you want to copy

Another way is `Collections.copy(desc,src)` but this is not feasible since the size of both the List  must be equal.